# Passing docker runtime environment variables in docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Here's my docker image. I want to override the default environment variables being set below from whatever is passed in the docker run command mentioned in the end

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ADD http://www.nic.funet.fi/pub/mirrors/apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.48/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.48.tar.gz /usr/local/
RUN cd /usr/local && tar -zxvf apache-tomcat-8.0.48.tar.gz && rm apache-tomcat-8.0.48.tar.gz
RUN mv /usr/local/apache-tomcat-8.0.48 /usr/local/tomcat
RUN rm -rf /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/*

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV CATALINA_HOME /usr/local/tomcat
ENV CATALINA_BASE /usr/local/tomcat
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$CATALINA_HOME/bin

ENV dummy_url defaulturl
ENV database databasedefault

COPY my.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

RUN echo >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
RUN echo dummy_url =$dummy_url >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
RUN echo database =$database >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties

ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

To run in local :

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e dummy_url=http:google.com -e database=jdbc://mysql allimages/myimage:latest
```

dummy_url and database do not seem to be getting overridden in the file that I am adding them in - test.properties. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i think you write to file env variables before overriding it. Try to enter into container `docker exec -it <container_name>` and run `printenv`.

Comment: Again, as I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40873165/use-docker-run-command-to-pass-arguments-to-cmd-in-dockerfile/40873331?noredirect=1#comment83384105_40873331, RUN is compile-time only (docker build). Your properties file is already set. You need your ENTRYPOINT to call a script which will do what your RUN commands do, and call catalina.sh.

Comment: Yes, I tried using docker exec to see the changed properties but they were still set to default. Will try out what @VonC has mentioned

Comment: I will post an answer later today (I am at work right now)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to override the default environment variables being set below from whatever is passed in the docker run command mentioned in the end

That means overriding an image file (`/usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties`) when *running* the image as a container ([`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)), not *building* the image ([`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) and its [`--build-args` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables-build-arg) and its [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) Dockerfile entry).

That means you create locally a script file which:

- modifies `/usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties`
- calls `catalina.sh run $@` (see also "[Store Bash script arguments $@ in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30439949/6309)" from "[Accessing bash command line args `$@` vs `$*`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28099707/6309)")

That is:

```
myscript.sh

#!/bin/sh
echo dummy_url=$dummy_url >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
echo database=$database >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
args=("$@")
catalina.sh run "${args[@]}"
```

You would modify your [Dockerfile to `COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) that script and call it:

```
COPY myscript.sh /usr/local/
...
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/myscript.sh"]
```

Then, and only then, the `-e` options of docker run would work.

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I was able to achieve this yesterday. I am accepting this answer because it addresses the issue exactly and is clear and concise.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing what gets executed when building the image and what gets executed when starting the container.
The `RUN` command inside the dockerfile is executed when building the image, when running `docker build ...`

```
RUN echo dummy_url =$dummy_url >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
RUN echo database =$database >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
```

Thus when the above execute the file `test.properties` will contain the default values specified in the Dockerfile.

When you execute `docker run -p 8080:8080 -e dummy_url=http:google.com -e database=jdbc://mysql allimages/myimage:latest` the `ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "run"]` will get executed with
env values `dummy_url=http:google.com` and `database=jdbc://mysql`.

You can allow values in test.properties to be ovveriden using:

1. Move `$dummy_url >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties` and `$database >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties` to the start of `catalina.sh` script.

---

2. Override the values when building the image as such:

---

```
ARG dummy_url_arg
ARG database_arg

ENV dummy_url $dummy_url_arg
ENV database $database_arg

COPY my.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/

RUN echo >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
RUN echo dummy_url =$dummy_url >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
RUN echo database =$database >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties

ENTRYPOINT ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And when **building** the image override the values using `docker build --build-arg dummy_url_arg=http:google.com --build-arg database_arg=jdbc://mysql allimages/myimage:latest ...`

Comment: Thanks! How can I create a new script instead, which includes the move commands above and then calls catalina.sh? What would the entrypoint look like? I tried doing this using the build command like you mentioned but because I would deploying an ECS task and passing these parameters from there, I wanted to avoid doing this as a build step

Comment: Also, instead of that, if I set all these properties under CATALINA_OPTS="-Ddummy_url=http://google.com -Ddatabase=somedb", how can I ensure that these get picked up and test.properties gets updated. I would prefer using the original catalina.sh and either use CATALINA_OPTS or a separate .sh which triggered catalina.sh

Comment: create a new script with following `$dummy_url >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
$database >> /usr/local/tomcat/conf/test.properties
sh ./catalania.sh run` and change `ENTRYPOINT ["script.sh", "run"]`

Comment: I get this weird error - standard_init_linux.go:185: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
My .sh file starts with #!/bin/bash followed by all echo property1=$property1 >> /usr/local/tomcat/test.properties statements and then just adding $CATALINA_HOME/bin/catalina.sh run

Comment: I also tried #!/bin/sh on top of the script I wrote but getting the same error

Comment: Ok, this worked after I followed some instructions here on the error above - http://willi.am/blog/2016/08/11/docker-for-windows-dealing-with-windows-line-endings/ thanks for your help!